# c# Intercept incoming call for Windows 10 Mobile 10586

Tags: windows-runtime, background-process, windows-10-mobile, incoming-call

Android and IOS, both have API to intercept incoming calls. Is this possible in this compilation of Windows 10 Mobile??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.aspx) and [Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.communicationblocking.aspx) namespaces and the [Communication blocking and filtering sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CommunicationBlockAndFilter)